# Get graphic width

Tags: graphics, floats, width

I'd like to have a command for inserting images in a figure with a width given by either the dimension of the raw image or the text width, whichever is smaller. I'd like to avoid blowing up images but also over-filling a page. Doing it manually isn't an option unfortunately. I've looked for a way to get the width of a graphic before inserting it and found nothing so far. Something along the lines of the following.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\newfigure}[1]{\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\ifnum\value{figwidth}<\textwidth {figwidth} \else {\textwidth}\fi]{#1}
\end{figure}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `adjustbox` (which loads `graphicx`). The command `\maxsizebox` allows you to place an upper bound on the dimensions of the content. Specifically,

```
\maxsizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}
```

leaves the width unchanged unless it exceeds the `\textwidth`, in which case it scales it down to the `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\maxsizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}\par
\bigskip

\noindent
\maxsizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics[width=20cm]{example-image-duck}}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `adjustbox` with the `export` option. The example uses A5 paper so the first image has to be scaled down. The third image shows that no scaling is done to the second image.

In case of very big images you might want to use also `max height` and `keepaspectratio`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image-1x1}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]